# Is it Halal to watch drama on television if the actors are modestly dressed?

Tags: halal-haram

I often hear others say that watching TV is Haram. My question is, for drama in which men and women all are in normal clothes, meaning they are not naked, nor are there any nude scenes, and with a great story, is watching this type of drama also Haram? are there any authentic/reliable sources which supports it is Haram?

Comment: Not sure what the answer is, buy why do people like wasting a large chunk of their life on such useless things?

Comment: because i like stories very much. and in all tv channels i only like one drama i was regularly wathing the episodes but from the day i know watching tv is haram i stopped it i only want to know that is wathing this type of drama is also haram?

Comment: My country's local Islamic channels show drama series all the time. I don't think they would if it were haraam.

Answer (score 8):

*Asking "Is watching Drama haraam?", is like asking "Is a pencil haraam?" where both questions can't be answered unless the questions are given further direction, as in their current state, are too general and can't be answered with any useful meaning.


For example: Is a pencil haraam? No, but it can be used for haraam!  Therefore, using that style of thought, I have tried to give your question some much needed direction to make it more of a valid question.  Keeping all that in mind, please read the answer below.


Please note that this answer is not about looking at non-covered men/women, it's about looking at covered and/or appropriately dressed men/women, which is me trying to add further direction to the question asked as explained above.*

We know that we have been told to lower our gaze.  The prophet of Islam would lower his gaze when women would pass in camel-borne sedan chairs, i.e. he would lower his gaze even when he could hardly see the women as they were covered in sedan chairs:

> In Saheeh Muslim (1218) it is reported that Al-Fadl ibn ‘Abbaas (may
>   Allaah be pleased with him) was riding behind the Messenger of Allaah
>   (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) on the Day of Sacrifice
>   (Yawm al-Nahr) from Muzdalifah to Mina, **when some women riding on
>   camel-borne sedan chairs passed by. The Messenger of Allaah (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him) turned his [al-Fadl’s] head away**.
>   This was prevention and denunciation through action, for if looking
>   were permissible he would have approved of what he did.

Here is an example of what sedan chairs probably looked like in those days considering the required cover from the burning desert sun:

[image]

We also know that both men and women have been told to lower their gaze:

> “**Tell the believing men to lower their gaze** (from looking at forbidden
>   things), and protect their private parts (from illegal sexual acts).
>   That is purer for them. Verily, Allâh is All-Aware of what they do.
>   And **tell the believing women to lower their gaze** (from looking at
>   forbidden things), and protect their private parts (from illegal
>   sexual acts)” [al-Noor 24:30-31].

So, it doesn't really seem to matter if they are wearing "normal cloths" or revealing cloths, it seems you should be lowering your gaze no matter how well covered the opposite gender is.

Therefore, if you're male and the drama you watch does not have females, and if you're female and the drama you watch has no males, then it "might" be all good.  However, all I can really say is, watch at your own risk.

*Source of quoted text: [islamqa](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7514/what-does-islam-say-about-watching-good-drama).

Source of example image: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_train).*

Comment: It's important not to present the words of a Muhaddith (who does not have universal agreement in the various Islamic denominations) as the words of the Prophet.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the people are "modestly dressed" (I'm assuming non Muslims and Muslims on TV) you are looking at the face of the opposite sex and may/will find the face attractive. Scholars even say watching the news with a female presenter is not allowed never mind dramas! You have other options wait until it's a male newsreader, read a newspaper, listen to the radio etc. if you miss the news does it mean you are missing out?

Comment: Please [Don't assume other users are male](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/954/dont-assume-other-users-are-male).

Answer (score 0):

Islam being a global and last religion elaborates wider principles in which characteristics of both Halal and haram are clearly defined. After given broader principles the way of ijtihad is advised  by ou religion by which with the collective wisdom of renowned islamic scholars of the time, decisions can be be made on all on going emerging  and future issues in the context of haram & Halal boundaries. This way of taking decision  is available in Hadith and  will remain enforced till the end of this universe. 
If we evaluate watching of drama or movie in same parameters than it can be easily decided that if available texture in drama / movie fulfills criteria of Halal properties as i have seen a movie named The Messenger and few dramas in which islamic history is shown with all pre requisites of Islamic clothing,  these types of films/movies are not Haram for Muslims. Likewise the movies / dramas of current productions having a texture of evil and  indecency are not permissible in islam being containing haram texture..