# Is watching movies or dramas is haram?

Tags: hadith, practical-islam

as we watch movies or drama so in Islam it is considered as haram. I am very confused because we watch daily a drama.

Answer (score 0):

[Is it Halal to watch drama on television if the actors are modestly dressed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7514/is-it-halal-to-watch-drama-on-television-if-the-actors-are-modestly-dressed)

Check this site I think u get ur answer after reading this. This question is already asked